# Understanding the usage of map/reduce functions in couchdb

Tags: nosql, couchdb

I have the below output key value pairs after my map function.

```
["hello"] => 12
["hello"] => 1
["world"] => 23
["world"] => 4
["canada"] => 18
```

When i use **__count** as the reduce function, i got the **result 5** as below.
System counts every row.

```
{
    "rows": [
        {
            "key": null,
            "value": 5
        }
    ]
}
```

I use the same map function with **__count** again.. This time i add **group=true** to the query. I get the below result. It seems like reduce function works for every grouped key and counts them in itself.

```
["hello"] => 2
["world"] => 2
["canada"] => 1
```

I can't understand the mechanism here.. Why the system works like this with and without grouping. If reduce function works for **every unique key** , Shouldn't the result without grouping be like below?

```
["hello"] => 1
["hello"] => 1
["world"] => 1
["world"] => 1
["canada"] => 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `reduce=true&group=false` and a `_count` reduce function you're asking the system to count the total number of entries in the index. Hence, you see the expected result of 5 in your case.

The `group=true` is a request to apply the reduce function at a per-key level only, and not do the final summation across all entries. As you can see, if you sum the values you get from the `group=true` case, you end up with the value you get for the `group=false` case: 2+2+1 = 5.

It gets even more complicated if you emit a vector-valued key, for example where your map says something along the lines of

```
emit([doc.field1, doc.field2, doc.field3], 1)
```

Then you can do the grouping at a select level of the precise number of values from the key that you want to group at, using `group_level=X`. This is often used when dealing with time-series type data, to be able to group per year, or per month or per day. This is explained in depth in the following blog-post:

https://console.bluemix.net/docs/services/Cloudant/blog/mapreduce.html